# cakephp bake 2 tables with a join table

Tags: join, cakephp-1.3

I have two tables. First table is a table of categories called `categories`, the second is a table of documents called `documents`. I'm trying to create a join table that will allow multiple categories to be applied to multiple documents and bake it all in seconds with CakePHP (to which I am a noob).

I've used mysql like this for the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cat_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `documents` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `size` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `file` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `date` date default NULL,
  `created` datetime default NULL,
  `modified` datetime default NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `categories_documents` (
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `document_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`,`document_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

...for the tables and was under the impression I got from what I read in the documentation that it would bake auto-magically. However I get lots of unknown column errors. I am wondering if I messed up on the naming conventions and if someone could put me right before I spent too long digging too deep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categories_documents will need an "id" field that needs to be the primary key.  That should fix it.  For more information, read the [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) documentation.

Comment: My original source was flawed, the documentation pointed to by both answers indicated that making the two ids in the link file primary was bad practice in CakePHP and the addition of the id as described here fixed it all. cake bake and the magic all happened.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think this link might help explain things to you better than I can: http://book.cakephp.org/view/872/Joining-tables

My experience have been manually writing all model codes, never used bake.